# How to select rows from multiindex dataframe based on a condition in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindex dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = {'C': {('S', 0): 'A',
  ('S', 2): 'A',
  ('T', 0): 'A',
  ('T', 1): 'A',
  ('T', 3): 'A',
  ('U', 1): 'A',
  ('U', 2): 'A',
  ('U', 0): 'A',
  ('V', 0): 'A',
  ('W', 2): 'A',
  ('W', 0): 'A',
  ('X', 0): 'A',
  ('Y', 3): 'A',
  ('Z', 0): 'A',
  ('Z', 1): 'A'},
 'D': {('S', 0): '15',
  ('S', 2): '22',
  ('T', 0): '20',
  ('T', 1): '20',
  ('T', 3): '20',
  ('U', 1): '18',
  ('U', 2): '14',
  ('U', 0): '14',
  ('V', 0): '14',
  ('W', 2): '22',
  ('W', 0): '25',
  ('X', 0): '15',
  ('Y', 3): '17',
  ('Z', 0): '04',
  ('Z', 1): '16'},
 'E': {('S', 0): 1.0,
  ('S', 2): 1.0,
  ('T', 0): 2.0,
  ('T', 1): 2.0,
  ('T', 0): 2.0,
  ('U', 1): 2.0,
  ('U', 2): 2.0,
  ('U', 0): 2.0,
  ('V', 0): 1.0,
  ('W', 2): 1.0,
  ('W', 0): 1.0,
  ('X', 0): 1.0,
  ('Y', 3): 2.0,
  ('Z', 0): 3.0,
  ('Z', 1): 3.0}}
```

I want to keep the level 0 rows if in its level 1 there is a value >=2

the output will look something like this:

```
outp = {'C': {('S', 0): 'A',
  ('S', 2): 'A',
  ('T', 0): 'A',
  ('T', 1): 'A',
  ('T', 3): 'A',
  ('U', 1): 'A',
  ('U', 2): 'A',
  ('U', 0): 'A',
  ('W', 2): 'A',
  ('W', 0): 'A',
  ('Y', 3): 'A'},
 'D': {('S', 0): '15',
  ('S', 2): '22',
  ('T', 0): '20',
  ('T', 1): '20',
  ('T', 3): '20',
  ('U', 1): '18',
  ('U', 2): '14',
  ('U', 0): '14',
  ('W', 2): '22',
  ('W', 0): '25',
  ('Y', 3): '17'},
 'E': {('S', 0): 1.0,
  ('S', 2): 1.0,
  ('T', 0): 2.0,
  ('T', 1): 2.0,
  ('T', 0): 2.0,
  ('U', 1): 2.0,
  ('U', 2): 2.0,
  ('U', 0): 2.0,
  ('W', 2): 1.0,
  ('W', 0): 1.0,
  ('Y', 3): 2.0}}
```

What I did is I got the value from level 0 when level 1 >= 2, but because when doing this I deleted the values 0 and 1 from level 1 that should stay, I had to create another dataframe with the gotten values and then merge using 'inner'.  I got the desired output but for sure I took the long and probably stupid way.

How could I do this in a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try with [`groupby filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) on `level=0` and filter to keep level 0 values when there is [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) value in index level 1 ([`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)) greater than or equal to 2:

```
outp = (
    df.groupby(level=0)
        .filter(lambda s: (s.index.get_level_values(1) >= 2).any())
)
```

`outp`:

```
     C   D    E
S 0  A  15  1.0
  2  A  22  1.0
T 0  A  20  2.0
  1  A  20  2.0
  3  A  20  NaN
U 1  A  18  2.0
  2  A  14  2.0
  0  A  14  2.0
W 2  A  22  1.0
  0  A  25  1.0
Y 3  A  17  2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the indices in level 0, where level 1 >= 2, and index the main `df` :

```
df.loc[df.query("ilevel_1 > =2").index.get_level_values(0)]

     C   D    E
S 0  A  15  1.0
  2  A  22  1.0
T 0  A  20  2.0
  1  A  20  2.0
  3  A  20  NaN
U 1  A  18  2.0
  2  A  14  2.0
  0  A  14  2.0
W 2  A  22  1.0
  0  A  25  1.0
Y 3  A  17  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way:

```
(df.loc[df.reset_index(level=1)
        .groupby(level=0)['level_1']
        .transform(lambda x: x.ge(2).any()).to_numpy()])
```

or

```
df.loc[df.index.to_frame().groupby(0)[1].transform(lambda x: x.ge(2).any())]
```